# Average values in multiple dictionaries?

Tags: python

I have 4 dictionaries where I have `symbol` as my key and `LTP` as the value. Now I want to create a new dictionary where I want the `symbol` as my key and average of `LTP` of 4 dictionary as my value

```
first = {"MRF":40000,"RELIANCE":1000}
second = {"MRF":50000,"RELIANCE":2000}
third = {"MRF":30000,"RELIANCE":500}
fourth = {"MRF":60000,"RELIANCE":4000}

new = {"MRF":45000,"RELIANCE":1875}  # this is the average of ltp
```

Kindly assist me with a way to do it ?

Comment: For starters, make that a *list* of four dicts, not four variables. Who is supposed to be in the mood to work with four variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get this using **mean** method in **statistics** library and list comprehension.

Here is the code :

Note: assuming that keys in all dictionaries are the same:

Note: I am using Python3.x for the below code:

```
from statistics import mean 

first = {"MRF":40000,"RELIANCE":1000}
second = {"MRF":50000,"RELIANCE":2000}
third = {"MRF":30000,"RELIANCE":500}
fourth = {"MRF":60000,"RELIANCE":4000}

dictionaryList = [first,second,third,fourth]
new = {}

for key in first.keys():
    new[key] = mean([d[key] for d in dictionaryList ])
print(new)
```

It Produces the exact same result that you needed

> {'MRF': 45000, 'RELIANCE': 1875}

Comment: Simply iterate on `first` instead of `first.keys()`

Answer (score 1):

```
first = {"MRF":40000,"RELIANCE":1000}
second = {"MRF":50000,"RELIANCE":2000}
third = {"MRF":30000,"RELIANCE":500}
fourth = {"MRF":60000,"RELIANCE":4000}

dicts = [first, second, third, fourth]
keys = first.keys()
new = {k: sum((d[k] for d in dicts)) / len(dicts) for k in first.keys()}
print(new) ## {'MRF': 45000.0, 'RELIANCE': 1875.0}
```

Comment: Simply iterate on `first`, ditch `keys`